# Send 40 images via REST API

Tags: json, api, rest, base64

I need to send 40 Images through web API to mobile for an online quiz game. Currently i convert images to BASE64 and send them. However it takes to much time to process since its a long JSON response. Is there a better way to send these many images. E.G just send images link (e.g. http://54.218.86.111/img.jpg) in JSON instead of complete BASE64, but that would mean 40 calls to server for one game play. 
Please help me find a better solution.

Comment: Anyway server will be sending that much data no matter what technique you use. I will suggest to use sending URLs in response because client may make multiple async calls to download images in parallel. Most important thing is to use caching headers in response so that client shall not download the images again when he restart the game.

Comment: Thanks lokehs. I agree with using asynchronous downloading but that will effect my game logic which depends on how much time user took to answer. Also i cannot use caching to save images since every time it will return different questions. I am attaching the link which returns these forty images. See if i can improve that.
[link](http://54.218.86.111/jito/questions/1)